# Style Base.Theme.AppCompat multiple implementation Android studio 3.1.1

Tags: android, styles

Since the last update I'm getting some error in my `styles.xml`

The error, more specifically, is

> Cannot resolve symbol Base
>   Cannot resolve symbol Base.Theme

[image: Cannot resolve]

With a multiple implementations tooltip (on ctrl + click)
[image: Multiple implementation]
And those are the possible implementation it suggest to me.
[image: implementations]

I would have ignored this, since my app is compiling and running anyway, but this is causing some annoying problems with my preview rendering and I hate it (for example I can't click a preview element to go to the code).
[image]

I think the problem might be in some of my implementations any of them probably use an old version, but they are all updated and I don't really understand why it was working before.

Any idea of the problem? Here are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-recyclerview:0.9.25'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:WaveSwipeRefreshLayout:1.6'
    implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.1.0'
    implementation 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
    implementation 'com.github.pratikbutani:MultiSelectSpinner:c3051c6922'
    implementation 'com.github.BeppiMenozzi:TriStateToggleButton:1.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: did you try to invalidate cache and restart android studio

Comment: @NileshRathod yes, and it's not working.

Comment: ps: for whoever downvoted this, at least comment with a reason, since I think this question has all the informations needed and I don't really think this deserve a downvote ;)

Comment: agree with you @piergiorgiomisley

Comment: test case try to update version of depedency `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2`

Comment: @NileshRathod wow, downgrading appcompact to 27.0.2 like you said worked! but only appcompat, I don't have to change other dependencies or will not work anyway. Why does it have this behaviour?

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks for the help btw! if you want to answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  downgrading `dependencies` of appcompact to `27.0.2`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```